# Primary Constructor is not being compiled in C# 6.0

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, primary-constructor

I am trying to write a simple example of the Primary Constructor new feature in C# 6.0 but I am not able to compile it.
I have changed the Language version to c# 6.0 but it still doesn't work.

[image]

```
public class Person (string fName, string lName)
{
    public string FName { get; private set; } = fName;
    public string LName { get; private set; } = lName;
}
```

How can I make it compile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I am trying to write a simple example of the Primary Constructor new feature in C# 6.0 but I am not able to compile it. I have changed the Language version to c# 6.0 but it still doesn't work.

That feature was cut.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it. Do you know what was the reason?

Comment: @ehh: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/568820